Seeking feedback on experimental fight mechanic
This would be a sci-fi based rpg with playable alien species; some of which would suffer at speed and dexterity but would be better suited to absorb damage. To simulate this I have considered the following combat mechanic-
In the beginning of combat the offending character makes an attack dice roll and the defending character makes a dice roll to evade. If the attack roll exceeds the roll to evade, the offending character rolls a second time in an attempt to overcome the defender's armor (either the defending character's natural armor if it has any, or whatever armor he is wearing). Should the second roll exceed the defender's armor rating the attacker then rolls to see how much damage his weapon inflicts.

Attacker -> Hit Roll (HR)
Defender -> Evade Roll (ER)
(HR) > (ER) then Attacker -> Armor Roll (AR)
(AR) > Armor -> Damage Roll

Does this mechanic sound overly/unnecessarily complicated? Is there a simpler method to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Please update your question with details about this armor rating, how many and what kind of dices can attacker and defender have for the purpose of those rolls and how many attacks or chances to evade both characters have for every turn(? are there any turns?) overall if you adding this mechanic to existing system please update tags and rewrite the question :)

How does damage work? Are there hit points? Can't we just add more hit points to those creatures which are "better suited to absorb damage"?

This sounds very close to Wod: Attack roll, defense roll, damage roll, soak roll.
